# How to insert data using map into my Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

First I am saving data in this way [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpOIF.png)

```
Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String refernce = TextRef.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String nompdv = textNomPdv.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String etat = textEtatCommande.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String datecommande = TextDateCommande.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String produitcommande = textProduit.getEditText().getText().toString();
        String qntcommande = editTextProduitQnt.getEditText().getText().toString();


        DatabaseReference newPost = reference.child(refernce);
        newPost.child("refernce").setValue(refernce);
        newPost.child("nompdv").setValue(nompdv);
        newPost.child("etat").setValue(etat);
        newPost.child("datecommande").setValue(datecommande);
        newPost.child("user_id").setValue(uid);
    
        DatabaseReference newOrder = reference.child(refernce).child("produit");
        newOrder.child(produitcommande).setValue(qntcommande);
    }
});
```

This is [My database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT6z3.png)

I want to use map only for saving "produit" (data in red): "produitcommande" and "qntcommande":

[image: this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only update the values in the `produit` child, that can be done with:

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("D3", "51");
values.put("D5L", "41");

DatabaseReference produitRef = reference.child(refernce).child("produit");
produitRef.setValue(values);
```

If you want to update some properties of `produit`, but leave the others unmodified, you can do that with:

```
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("D3", "51");
values.put("D6", "new value");

DatabaseReference produitRef = reference.child(refernce).child("produit");
produitRef.updateChildren(values);
```

This will *update* `D3`, will add a new `D6` property, and will leave `D5L` unmodified.

Comment: Thanks, I finished by adding products like that :  `` values.put(produitcommande, qntcommande); ``